# How to SIgn Up and Login Salesforce commerce cloud

Tags: e-commerce, commerce-cloud

I am New to salesforce commerce cloud, can you please help me to salesforce commerce cloud sign up and Login Process expalin me!

i thinking about salesforce commerce cloud and salesforce sales, and service cloud both are different (or) same.

i,m login/SignUp sales and service cloud by using login.salesforce.com / developer.salesforce.com.
but salesforce commerce cloud also same or any other way to login or sign Up.

Comment: can you please check this url: https://account.demandware.com/

Answer (score 0):

You currently cannot simply sign up without a signed (commerce cloud) contract in place.